# Mocking conditional computed property in Ember component test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ember.js

I'm trying to simply mock the computed property return value before rendering a component. Trying `this.set('isHome', true)` does not work though because I can't pass it to the component.

**Component [Logic]:**

```
isHome: false
```

**Component [Template]:**

```
{{#if isInbox}}
  <p id="maintext">Text</p>
{{/if}}
```

**Test:**

```
test('Block is visible on the homepage', function(assert) {
  assert.expect(1);
  this.set('isHome', true); // Does nothing
  this.render(template);
  let maintext = this.$("#maintext")
  this.asyncWait(assert, () => {
    assert.ok(maintext);
  });
});
```

This is a very rough outline of the layout, with a computed property that then is used to show a block on the page or not. How would I override that computed property to `true` to force that block to show?

Answer (score 0):

Dug into this further with a colleague and they confirmed that trying to edit computed properties directly in a test should be avoided.

Instead, they suggested altering the values that would be used to set that ComputedProperty. In my case, I was checking if the current path includes a word.

So instead of trying to set the Computed Property to `true` instead I can mock the path and include the word I'm looking for so that it evaluates to `true`.

Hope this helps someone later on!